# Como não salvar m valor na lista caso if(vedadeiro)

Tags: c#

eu tenho um foreach percorrendo minha lista e eu quero que caso um if() seja verdadeiro ele mostre uma mensagem dizendo que já existe esse valor na lista e **NÃO ARMAZENE** esse valor na lista, alguém sabe como fazer ??

```
foreach (Agendamento agenda in Agendamentos)
            {
                if (agenda.matricula.Equals(matricula) && agenda.horarioAtendimento.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Equals(maisDeUmDia))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("JA EXISTE UM ATENDIMENTO PARA ESTA DATA");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("NÃO EXISTE UM ATENDIMENTO PARA ESTA DATA");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Recomendo usar métodos pronto como `.Any` ou `.Contains`

Answer (score 0):

Após instanciar o `Agedamento agenda;` e atribuir seus valores, você pode usar o método `.Contains()` da lista - para verificar se já existe o Agendamento.

Um exemplo:

```
if (Agendamentos.Contains(agenda))
{
    Console.WriteLine("JÁ EXISTE UM ATENDIMENTO PARA ESTA DATA");
}
else
{
    Agendamentos.Add(agenda);
    Console.WriteLine("ATENDIMENTO REGISTRADO");
}
```

Comment: show, vlw fera.

Comment: se ajudou, marca lá como útil.